# Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, java-11

This is my spring boot project. When I going to run gradle task in spring tool suit I can get error like below. I am new to sprint boot can anyone help me. I used java 11 and gradle version 6.8.3

```
Gradle Distribution: Specific Gradle version 6.8.3
Gradle Version: 6.8.3
Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: clean build

> Task :clean

> Task :compileJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :bootJarMainClassName
> Task :bootJar
> Task :jar SKIPPED
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test NO-SOURCE
> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: It isn't an error it is a warning stating that you are using deprecated features or ways of doing things which are going to be removed in newer gradle versions. If you don't address those your build might stop working when you are upgrading from gradle 6.8 to a newer version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `./gradlew build --warning-mode all` to find out deprecated features.

For example
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be for several reasons, To avoid going into so much explanation If the application worked at some point

1. Delete de app in the device and run yarn android or npm android
   or
2. Delete de build folder and delete the app in the device and run yarn android or npm android

That's works for me

Answer (score 0):

I have this same error, and ask me to upgrade to compatible gradle 9.0, while I am using gradle 8.
in fact, the problem is not about gradle version, I forgot to add icon rounded in android src folder,

make sure all icon is provided before build

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).